# Trigger parent onClick when clicking children

Tags: javascript, reactjs

In ReactJS, how can I trigger the `onClick` listener of the parent `div`, regardless of whether or not the click is fired over a child element? With the following code, `onItemClick` is only triggered if I click somewhere in the parent `div` where the children are not present.

```
<div class={className} onClick={this.onItemClick}>
    <Row key={"row_"+id}>
        <Col><FormGroup controlId={"name"}><Form.Control type="text" disabled value={name}/></FormGroup></Col>
        <Col><FormGroup controlId={"status"}><Form.Control type="text" disabled value={status}/></FormGroup></Col>
        <Col><FormGroup controlId={"warmth"}><Form.Control type="text" disabled value={warmth}/></FormGroup></Col>
    </Row>
</div>
```

Comment: Event delegation shall help: https://javascript.info/event-delegation

Comment: It might be because of your children components have their own `onClick` function.

Answer (score 0):

You can give parent's onclick function to the child with props and call this.props.onClick in the div onClick of the child.